# MySQL Get COUNT and SUM in a Single Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I use this query:

```
SELECT 
      `o_p`.`id`, 
      `o`.`user_id` AS `buyer`,
      `product_number` 
FROM `order_products` `o_p` 
LEFT JOIN `order` `o` ON o.id=o_p.id 
WHERE (`o_p`.`product_id`='5') AND (`o`.`pay_status`=1)
```

then i get this result:

```
id buyer product_number

20 7     13

26 7     10

27 19    10
```

or you can see the result at this [**link**](http://7sbygn.com2.z0.glb.qiniucdn.com/17jinkou_64792FF9-01FD-42AE-B101-F3F42E0A5756.png)

But I want to count the buyer's number which is expected '2',and the total of `product_number` which is expected '33'.

How should I fix the query.

Answer (score 1):

Use `count(distinct user_id)` for the # of unique buyers and `sum(product_number)` for the total of product_number

```
select count(distinct o.user_id) as buyer_number,
sum(product_number) as product_number_total
from order_products o_p 
left join order o on o.id=o_p.id 
where (o_p.product_id='5') and (o.pay_status=1)
```

Comment: @Rigel1121 It seems op wants the sum and count for the entire table and not per id because the example contains multiple ids yet the desired result are the counts and sums of the entire table

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(o.user_id)` for the number of unique buyers and `SUM(product_number)` for the total of product_number. Lastly, `GROUP BY o.user_id`.

```
SELECT
      COUNT(o.user_id) AS buyer_number,
      SUM(product_number) AS product_number_total
FROM order_products o_p 
LEFT JOIN order o ON o.id=o_p.id 
WHERE (o_p.product_id='5') AND (o.pay_status=1)
GROUP BY o.user_id
```